# C# get actual GMT time

Tags: c#, time, utc, gmt

does a function that return to me the actual GMT shift exist?
Like, in France its actually GMT+02.
So it would return : +02

Tried with some function such as

```
DateTime.UtcNow;
```

So yea i could compare the UTC time to my actual time to get the GMT+x but if something that do it automaticly exist i'll take it

Comment: you want to look at the TimeZoneInfo class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset` might be what you're looking for. Check the code sample in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See duplicate and this: `var  gmt = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");`